# How to save udp stream to .ts files whith ffmpeg while keeping timestamp?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to record a live udp stream containing multiple TV programs ( up to 30 ) to .ts files .To do so i'm using FFMPEG .

I have a muxer at work , but i dont go there everyday so im using a sample .ts file containing 15 minutes recording of all the tv channels , but i tried on both and i got same results so i guess thats not a problem .The TS file is basically the same as udp , but just as a file . Same timebase , encoding , programs

here is the code i am using :

```
ffmpeg -i "d:\record ts\PBR_REC_20140426094852_485.ts" -f segment -segment_time 300 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map 0:p:1202 "file:C:\Users\vlatkozelka\Desktop\TEST\%date:~10%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%03d.ts"
```

this is extracting one tv channel , program 1202 , and recording files in this format : DateTime001 ,DateTime002 .... 5 minutes each.

now when i run these in a player i made in JAVA, which is the purpose of these, ... i can see the timestamp is reset to 00:00:00 for each file beginning. I know its not a problem in the player itself cuz i tried with other files and the timestamps are ok.

I tried adding -copyts which for some strange reason seems to segment to 1 second long files , i tried -copytb 1 , 0 , -1 , all failed , tried -vsync passthrough , also failed (i also tried cominations of these ) And from what ive read FFMPEG guards timecode as it is by default , the build im using is fairly new i downloaded it like a month ago . And i know also that FLV requires resetting timecode , but TS is used for transport so shouldnt do this ... any ideas ?Also is there a way to slow down the copying from file to file , cuz its too fast its killing my HDD ( i mean from the .ts to the .ts not the actual udp )?

**UPDATE** : i tried again and it seems -copyts is doing the trick but the output files are that short cuz timebase issues . So i tried increasing -setgment_time to 2000 ... it recorded 6  shorter than a seconf files ... and all the rest of the vid onto aother file .
here is the output im getting :

Logs:

```
ffmpeg version N-64167-gca35037 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 22 2014 22:02:17 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 90.100 / 52. 90.100
  libavcodec     55. 68.100 / 55. 68.100
  libavformat    55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 049f2620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0035be80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 049f2620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0035be80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 049f2620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 047e0180] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 047e0180] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0035be80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp2 @ 04850fa0] Header missing
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 049f2620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 047e0180] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mp2 @ 0481e5e0] Header missing
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048bc820] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 048899a0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mpeg2video @ 04ba1b80] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04ebe5c0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 04b9ff60] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 22 times
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Stream #20: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Stream #23: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Stream #25: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Stream #27: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[mpegts @ 003590a0] decoding for stream 18 failed
[NULL @ 04b9f340] start time for stream 20 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04b9ef40] start time for stream 21 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba1fa0] start time for stream 23 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04b9f740] start time for stream 24 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba23a0] start time for stream 25 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04b9eb20] start time for stream 26 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba1380] start time for stream 27 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04b9fb40] start time for stream 28 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba1780] start time for stream 29 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba0360] start time for stream 30 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[NULL @ 04ba0760] start time for stream 31 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 003590a0] PES packet size mismatch
    Last message repeated 11 times
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 18 (Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 20 (Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 21 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 23 (Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 24 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 25 (Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 26 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 27 (Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 28 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 29 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 30 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mpegts @ 003590a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 31 (Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'd:\record ts\PBR_REC_20140426094852_485.ts':
  Duration: 00:13:34.27, start: 10174.735589, bitrate: 42155 kb/s
  Program 1201 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Arabica TV
      service_provider: Nilesat
    Stream #0:17[0x7db]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2348 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0xbcf]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
  Program 1202 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : NBN
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:32[0x7d1]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:14[0xbba](eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1203 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Heya TV
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:13[0x7d2]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:8[0xbbc](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1204 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : AL JADEED
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:18[0x7d3]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:22[0xbbe](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1205 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : MANAR
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:3[0x7d4]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:4[0xbc0](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 93 kb/s
  Program 1206 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Lebanon TV
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:12[0x7d6]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2800 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:9[0xbcb](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1207 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Test
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:20[0x7d7]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 90k tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:21[0xbc9]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1209 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Test
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:23[0x7d9]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 90k tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:24[0xbcd]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1210 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Test
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:27[0x7da]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 90k tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:28[0xbce]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1211 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Test
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:25[0x7dc]: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 90k tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:26[0xbd0]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1213 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : MTV Lebanon
      service_provider: Nilesat
    Stream #0:0[0x7dd]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 4595 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xbd1](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 220 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0xbd2](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 188 kb/s
  Program 1215 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Sumaria
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:11[0x7d0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2800 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:16[0xbb8](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1216 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Hawacom
      service_provider: Nilesat
    Stream #0:7[0xbc5]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], max. 2705 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:19[0xbc6](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1220 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RFI
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:10[0xbb9](eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 188 kb/s
  Program 1221 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Sumer FM
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:15[0xbbb](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 125 kb/s
  Program 1222 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Leb Radio 3
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:29[0xbbd]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1223 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Leb Radio 4 
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:30[0xbbf]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
  Program 1224 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : NOUR
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:5[0xbc1](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 94 kb/s
  Program 1225 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Leb Radio 6 
      service_provider: NILESAT
    Stream #0:31[0xbc7]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels
[segment @ 049f2a00] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 050f29a0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, segment, to 'file:C:\Users\vlatkozelka\Desktop\TEST\201420082153%03d.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.44.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, 125 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg2video ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, max. 2600 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:14 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:32 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 04ebbf80] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 047df3c0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 050f29a0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 04b5abc0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 050f29a0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 13 times
[mpegts @ 04ebbfe0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 04bbea80] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 050f29a0] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame= 1118 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:36:26.96 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 2342 fps=2339 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:37:15.92 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 3623 fps=2412 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:38:07.16 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 4937 fps=2466 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:38:59.72 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 6278 fps=2509 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:39:53.36 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 7659 fps=2550 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:40:48.60 bitrate=N/A    
frame= 9001 fps=2569 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:41:42.28 bitrate=N/A    
frame=10337 fps=2582 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:42:35.72 bitrate=N/A    
frame=11669 fps=2591 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:43:29.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=12993 fps=2596 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:44:21.96 bitrate=N/A    
[mpegts @ 003590a0] PES packet size mismatch
frame=14345 fps=2606 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:45:16.88 bitrate=N/A    
frame=15593 fps=2596 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:46:06.80 bitrate=N/A    
frame=16976 fps=2609 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:47:02.12 bitrate=N/A    
frame=18365 fps=2621 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:47:57.68 bitrate=N/A    
frame=19705 fps=2625 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=08:48:51.28 bitrate=N/A    
[mpegts @ 003590a0] PES packet size mismatch
frame=20299 fps=2560 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=08:49:15.04 bitrate=N/A    

video:253752kB audio:12697kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: im real sorry , i only noticed this is the right place after i added the tag ... other post deleted .

Comment: I have had similar issue when trying to record an _opus_ stream into segments while retaining timestamps. It might be a bug in `ffmpeg`. Have you informed developers about this? BTW you might better use `stream_segment` instead of `segment` in the command.